# SharePoint Forms Based Authentication Cookie Lifetime

Tags: cookies, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, forms-authentication

Can someone please tell me how exactly we should configure different cookie lifetimes and session timouts for SharePoint Forms Based authenticated website?

I came across following lifetimes:

1. LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow
2. FormsTokenLifetime
3. CookieLifetime
4. CookieLifetimeRefreshWindow

Could you please explain relation between these values, and how these values affect each other?

I am curious about all of the above because whenever I refresh the FedAuth cookie only by considering it's expiry time, I get errors related to authentication sometimes.